# How to open a directory (using Explorer) that contains a user defined input string

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a batch file to open (with explorer) a user specified folder from a directory. The desired folder would only need to contain the input string (number) and all sub-directories in this directory follow the same naming format:
"xxx xxx-%INPUT% yyyy...".

The issue I am having is there are also unique descriptions after the %INPUT% number of the directories (shown as "y" in naming format example). Is there any way to ignore these descriptions and just open the folder beginning with the string "xxx xxx-%INPUT%" or simply containing the %INPUT% (as this would also be unique)? I tried using an asterisk after xxx xxx-%INPUT% and hoped the find or find string commands could help but no such luck.

Here is my current code, thanks in advance for your assistance

```
@ECHO OFF
C:
CD\
CLS

:MENU
CLS

ECHO ======= Input Job Number ========

SET /P INPUT=Please input job number or press 'Q' to quit...

IF /I '%INPUT%'=='Q' GOTO Quit
IF %INPUT% LSS 1000 set INPUT=0%INPUT%

IF NOT EXIST "P:\a\b\c\%INPUT%" GOTO INVALID ELSE GOTO NOWINDIR ::ideally this would check if any folder contains the input string

::NOWINDIR

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "P:\a\b\c\%INPUT%" ::ideally this would open the folder containing that input string

::Invalid

CLS

ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO Please input valid job number or 'Q' to quit.
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO MENU

::Quit
EXIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
C:
CD\

:MENU
CLS

ECHO ======= Input Job Number ========

:again
SET "INPUT=Q"
SET /P INPUT=Please input job number or press 'Q' to quit...

IF /I "%INPUT%"=="Q" GOTO Quit
set INPUT=0000%INPUT%
set INPUT=%INPUT:~-4%

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (
 'dir /b /ad "U:\a\b\c\*%INPUT%*" 2^>nul'
 ) DO SET "input=U:\a\b\c\%%i"&GOTO nowindir

::Invalid

ECHO ============INVALID INPUT %input%===========
GOTO again

:NOWINDIR

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "%INPUT%"

:Quit
GOTO :EOF

EXIT
```

This should get you started.

`SET /P` leaves the variable unchanged if the user simply presses <kbd>enter</kbd>. Normally, it would be an idea to `SET` the variable's value to an empty string to ensure stale data isn't unexpectedly retained, but in this case, you can initialise it to a default. The quoted arguments ensure that any stray spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to the variable.

Rabbit's ears enclose strings in batch, not single-quotes. Use this on each side of the comparison to allow for strings containing spaces.

You've added an arbitrary `0` before the input string, which should work for 100..999 to convert it to a 4-character numeric string. You imply that yur target is a 4-character numeric string, but don't say so explicitly. What happens for 1..99?

Stringing `0000` before the input data, then setting the value to its own last 4 characters will ensure that the string is 4 characters long.

The `for/f` processes a `dir` listing of the target directory, produced in `/b` basic (names-only) form and `/ad` only the directories matching `*%input%*` (btw - the `*` character is an asterisk...) The `"delims="` clause ensures that the entire string including spaces is applied to `%%i` *if* a match is found.

If the match is found, `input` is set to the fullpath and processing switched to the label `:nowindir`, which runs explorer and then exits. I've added a `GOTO :EOF` there which ends the batch but does not terminate the `cmd.exe` session - for testing where the batch may need to be run repeatedly. In your case, you'd be likely to need to delete that `goto :eof` which will then cause the batch to `EXIT`

Note the difference between `:label` and `::comment` - actually, `::comment` is an unreachable label (as it starts with two `:`) but it's often preferred to the more intrusive `REM` statement.

I also added the (modified) input value to the `INVALID INPUT` line and simplified...

Finally, note that I used my `U:` drive for testing - you'd need to change that back to your `P:`

Comment: Thank you for the highly in-depth reply, and helping me learn more about batching. As you no doubt can see, I am new to it. You are correct that the target is a 4character numeric string. 1-99 is not applicable. Your advice and insight into my script has given me a lot to think and learn about. Thank you again